# How to create a structure with multiple sub-structures in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have the need to create a 'big' struct which will contain sub-structures in matlab.
In the problem i am trying to deal with, i have 560 variables, which , each one respectively has the domain D=[0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7].

For just one variable of the problem, lets say x0, i have done this and works just fine :

```
field='x0';
dom=domain_var;
d0=struct(field,dom);
d0
```

And the output is :

```
x0: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Which is actually fine.

`field` is actually the name of every single variable, f.e. `x0,x1,x2,...,x560` and when i declare  `dom=domain_var;` , `domain_var` is just a int array which contains the possible values for every variable, meaning `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` (it is the same for every variable of the problem).

The thing is, how could i do this not for just one, or for just two structs and then concatenate them, but for 560 variables? Is this possible? And if yes, how could this be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine `field` and `dom` for each?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, right. I forgot to mention that field is actually the name of every single varialbe, f.e. x0,x1,x2,...x560 and when i declare dom=domain_var; , domain_var is just a int array which containts the possible values for every variable, meaning [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] (it is the same for every variable of the problem).

Comment: It's hard to deal with different variables that way. You'd better define an 2D array or a cell array `x`

Comment: @LuisMendo Could you please be more specific?

Comment: If the contents of each variable should be for example `0:7`: pack all variables in a a 2D array: `[0:7; 0:7; 0:7]`. Then just use `x(1,:)`, `x(2,:)` etc. Or if they have different sizes, define a cell array: `x = {0:7, 0:5, 1:3};` and then use`x{1}`,  `x{2}` etc

Answer (score 1):

```
for ii=1:560,fnm=['x' num2str(ii)];d0.(fnm)=dom;end
```

should do the trick I guess?

Comment: Can you expand on that answer, and explain what the code is doing?